# Query about SVM classifier in R

Tags: r, dataset, classification, svm

I am working on a music data set where I have to classify the music data in to genres. I have both test and train data sets.
I have linked the datasets for you to check
[here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3lfvuqibwl61i9p/AADqmaL71amh0FFE_TLIKRn2a?dl=0)
I am working in Rstudio

Here's the code I have written. I am a beginner and have no clue what I am doing. I am shooting arrows randomly. Let me know if you need more information.

The library used is :-

```
library("e1071")
```

The code :-

`svm.model <- svm(GENRE ~ ., data = musictraindata, cost = 62.5, gamma = 0.5)`

Now my problem is what to put in x parameter. I have put "GENRE" from train data set but it's giving me the following error.

> Error in svm.default(x, y, scale = scale, ..., na.action = na.action) : 
>     Need numeric dependent variable for regression.

Someone please guide me on what I should do. Thanks.

After corrections :-
I ran the code with the said corrections.I got an svm.model as follows :-

```
svm.model

Call:
svm(formula = factor(GENRE) ~ ., data = musictraindata, cost = 62.5, gamma = 0.5, type = "C-classification", 
    tolerance = 0.01)

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  62.5 
      gamma:  0.5 
Number of Support Vectors:  11880
```

Now I try to create a predict model by using it with test data.

```
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model,musictestdata)
```

When I plot the `svm.pred`, I get a graph as follows which is highly unlikely. Here it is:

[image: plot(svm.pred)]

This how I am suppose to proceed right ? Am I doing something wrong ?
Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough to say without a reproducible example, but I would confirm that the class of your dependent variable (Genre) is a factor, and doesn't have anything goofy going on like NA's.  Check this with `class(musictraindata$GENRE)`.  Also worth a note, R is cap-sensitive so "Genre" and "GENRE" make a difference.

You can also try specficying the type of SVM you want to run by using
`(type = "C-classification")`
and see if it throws you a more helpful error?

Comment: class(musictraindata$GENRE) is giving me " [1] "character" " as output. By running the code with (type = "C-classification") , Rstudio is taking a lot of time to process. I will update the post if I get some output. Meanwhile let me know if I can do something else or you need any more information. Thanks again.

Comment: `svm.model <- svm(factor(GENRE) ~ ., data = musictraindata, cost = 62.5, gamma = 0.5)` should work, or you can use `musictraindata$GENRE <- factor(musictraindata$GENRE)` and run your original svm code.  You need Genre to be a factor, not a character.

Comment: try `summary(factor(musictraindata$GENRE))` to make sure it has the correct genres in there.  New to SO but if there is a chat/way for me to see your data I wouldnt mind helping out.

Comment: I did it. It worked as it should when I did a fresh run of the code. Thanks a ton !  PS : I may have sent a LinkedIN connect request to discuss the matter further but I guess it's resolved. Will ping you if I get caught up when I further dive into the dataset. :D